# How to avoid GameObject scrolling from propagating to RTSCamera zooming

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using the RTS Camera asset from the Unity store(https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/camera/rts-camera-43321) to have a camera for a unity scene.

The camera works fine, but I have a small but important problem. If I have one of my GameObjects in from the scene (say a dialog), which has a scrollbar, when i scroll my middle mouse button to go up and down the scroll, the scroll propagates back to the scene as well. Thus creating a funny outcome of both the scrollbar scrolling down and the scene zooming in.

Is there a way to get the RTS camera script to reject my mouse input while any of my gameobjects are on top of the scene ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a public field `useScrollwheelZooming` in RTS_Camera

Set it to false when you don't want to zoom the camera

.e.g `rtc_camera.useScrollwheelZooming = !EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject();`